# Declaring booleans Optimization

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

Will the java compiler optimize this:

```
boolean foo1 = getSomeHardToGetBoolean();
boolean foo2 = getSomeEasyToGetBoolean();
if(foo1 && foo2){
//do stuff
}
```

To this:

```
if(getSomeEasyToGetBoolean() && getSomeHardToGetBoolean()){
//do stuff
}
```

Or even this:

```
if(getSomeHardToGetBoolean() && getSomeEasyToGetBoolean()){
//do stuff
}
```

I use the first way as a general practice for readability, but at what cost?

*Side note: Java 8 is assumed. Using JIT. The booleans cannot be determined until runtime. The booleans are completely independent of each other. I probably won't stop using the first way either way, but I'm just curious. Thanks!*

Comment: Performance cost is neglible if you don't perforn this thousands times per second. Premature optimization is root of evil.

Comment: Which compiler do you mean (javac or the JIT)? And are `foo1` and `foo2` "constant," even if they're not formally constants by the JLS? Can you elaborate a bit more on what goes into them? And why wouldn't you just expect it to optimize all the way to just `if (false)`, and then remove the dead code? If you're worried about performance, note that even if the optimizer doesn't handle it, this could be very easy for a branch predictor.

Comment: @Ginden Understood. This is more of a curiosity question.

Comment: Write microbenchmark. After million runs you will see if it gots optimized.

Comment: @yshavit JIT. Neither foo1 nor foo2 are constant. This is not for a specific program, just a general question.

Comment: A good optimizer will optimize `if (foo1 && foo2);` to a null statement, since your code will not do anything whether the condition is true or false.  On the other hand, if you have an actual statement or block after the `if` instead of a semicolon, it's a more interesting question.

Comment: I edited the question based on your comments. Should be more interesting now.

Comment: @Holger "Value following".  If there's nothing between the above two declarations and the `if` that could change `foo1` or `foo2`, then a good optimizer can tell what the values will be at the point of the `if` statement, and can optimize accordingly.  (P.S. "Value following" is the term that was used in the optimizer I've worked on, but it may not be standard terminology.)

Comment: For rewritten question answer is "no". You can't expect strict evaluation to be translated to lazy evaluation if side effects are not known.

Comment: @Ginden it will go off and find out that the side effects don't mess with each other though, won't it?

Comment: @Evorlor Maybe.  In theory, the compiler could keep track of what side effects a method can have.  In practice, there's a limit to what an optimizer can do, if you want your program to take less than a year to compile.  If `getSomeEasyToGetBoolean` is simple enough, it may be possible.  But the only way to tell for sure with any particular compiler is to try it.  The language itself doesn't specify such things.

Comment: The optimizer doesn’t work like saying “this method has side-effects (or not)”. What it does is inlining both method’s code and then optimize the resulting block as a whole. Within that block there might be actions having specified behavior regarding their side-effects which inhibits certain optimizations. If two of such actions forbid moving code across them there is still the possibility of optimizing the code in-between them, including removal of unnecessary actions. So the resulting code might produce the observable side-effects but only these, still conditionally skipping other actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimizer has to maintain the semantics of a program. So, if `getSomeEasyToGetBoolean()` and `getSomeHardToGetBoolean()` have observable side-effects, the optimizer can’t elide these side-effects as that would change the semantics of your program.

But if these action don’t have observable side-effects, an optimizer will indeed perform such transformations as inlining, reordering and moving of conditionals to the beginning of a code block belong to the standard repertoire of an optimizer.

That’s the reason why multi-threaded programs accessing common data structures without proper synchronization constructs can break badly as in this case a thread might observe the changed behavior of a thread executing optimized code.

Comment: This answer and Ibalazscs answer/comments appear to contradict each other in my limited knowledge. Can you explain how these two answers meet please?

Comment: I assumed that the two methods are complicated enough so that the compiler has no way to determine with certainty that they have no side-effects.

Comment: lbalazscs’ answer is correct regarding that such optimizations aren’t allowed if the invoked methods have side-effects. (Therefore you can never write a program to test whether this optimization occurs) But it does not consider that HotSpot uses *aggressive inlining* to make it possible to detect whether there are such side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that `getSomeEasyToGetBoolean()` and `getSomeHardToGetBoolean()` might have side-effects, all three snippets of code have different functionality and it would be an error if the compiler mixed them

Comment: Good point. The third way is different. But the first two should be exactly the same I think

Comment: @Evorlor Nope. The first will always run both methods, the second one will sometimes only run the `getSomeEasyToGetBoolean()` method.

Comment: @Slanec ahh I'm confused now. So the compiler will NOT optimize from the first way to one of the second two?

Comment: @Evorlor The && operator stops evaluating if the first operand evaluates to false since the result will be false

Comment: @lbalazscs understood. So your saying the first way cannot possibly optimize to one of the later two ways assuming the foo1 and foo2 are completely independent of each other?

Comment: As Holger said, if the JIT will be able to prove that there are no side-effects to the methods, it will probably inline their code and optimize it into the form you want. Probably.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

It makes no sense for the *compiler* to optimise in that way, considering that the `if` statement may be nested within a loop, and the values of the booleans may change at runtime (after compilation, even with JIT)